# How to call Delphi FMX Factory method from C++ Builder

Tags: delphi, c++builder, firemonkey

In Delphi  FMX

```
TStyledPresentation = class(TStyledControl)
```

Method defined as:

```
function GetModel<T: TDataModel>: T;
```

And in the C++ hpp file as:

```
template<typename T> T __fastcall GetModel(void);
```

Implimented As:

```
function TStyledPresentation.GetModel<T>: T;
begin
Result := FModel as T;
end;
```

When overridden, allows returning a custom Model as it does  in TEdit as below:

```
function TCustomEdit.GetModel: TCustomEditModel;
begin
Result := GetModel<TCustomEditModel>;
end;
```

I have over ridden this in my .h file in C++ Builder as:

```
HIDESBASE TAltorFMXEditModel* __fastcall GetModel(void)/* overload */;
```

And Implimented it in the .cpp file as:

```
TAltorFMXEditModel * __fastcall TAltorFMXEdit::GetModel(void)
{
return GetModel<TAltorFMXEditModel>;
}
```

But this doesn't build or work.

Can someone please show me how to correctly call the Delphi factory method from C++ Builder?

Comment: If it *doesn't build*, then clearly it won't work, and you got an error message. What was that error message? It's on the screen right in front of you, and there is absolutely no reason for you to fail to include it in your post so we have that information as well.

Answer (score 1):

You wrote:

```
return GetModel<TAltorFMXEditModel>;
```

But this returns the function when in fact you need to call the function, and pass on its return value:

```
return GetModel<TAltorFMXEditModel>();
```

Delphi syntax allows you to omit the function call parens in some situations, but C++ syntax does not permit this.

I would expect that the C++ compiler would have reported an error message that indicated this.

Comment: Thank you David.  I tried

    return GetModel<TAltorFMXEditModel>();

result:

[bcc32c Error] AltorFMXEdit.cpp(56): 'TAltorFMXEditModel' does not refer to a value

Tried:

    return GetModel<__classid(TAltorFMXEditModel)>();

result

[bcc32c Error] AltorFMXEdit.cpp(57): invalid operands to binary expression ('TAltorFMXEditModel *(__closure *)() __attribute__((fastcall))' and 'TClass' (aka 'System::TMetaClass *'))

Does that get us any closer?

Comment: @David: I guess that is why it doesn't build. <g>

Comment: @Alan: It looks as if the compiler doesn't know what a `TAltorFMXEditModel` is supposed to be. Did you include the necessary header file?

Comment: Yes Rudy, the TAltorFMXEditModel .h file is included.  It's referenced in other methods in the same Unit with success.